# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckedTextView

Tags: android, inflate-exception

I have built an app loading url using a `WebView`. 
Within that WebView i am loading a form:

```
<select>
     <option value="1">Value1</option>
     <option value="2">Value2</option>
     ...
</select>
```

When the select field is clicked android will invoke android.widget.CheckedTextView
I have found that on some devices this causes a crash (see log below)

How can i avoid this crash? 
Do i need to extend WebView and add try{} before android invokes `CheckedTextView`.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckedTextView
in at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619).createFromXmlInner
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:467)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$InvokeListBox$MyArrayListAdapter.getView(WebViewClassic.java:12642)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2008)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1247)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1140)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:467)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$InvokeListBox$MyArrayListAdapter.getView(WebViewClassic.java:12642)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2008)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1247)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1140)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_btn_radio_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020008
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2810)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.CheckedTextView.<init>(CheckedTextView.java:67)
at android.widget.CheckedTextView.<init>(CheckedTextView.java:58)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:467)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$InvokeListBox$MyArrayListAdapter.getView(WebViewClassic.java:12642)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2008)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1247)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1140)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_btn_radio_on_mtrl.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02000a
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2810)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1522)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:917)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:854)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2807)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.CheckedTextView.<init>(CheckedTextView.java:67)
at android.widget.CheckedTextView.<init>(CheckedTextView.java:58)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:467)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$InvokeListBox$MyArrayListAdapter.getView(WebViewClassic.java:12642)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2008)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1247)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1140)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:913)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:854)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2807)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1522)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:917)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:854)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2807)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.CheckedTextView.<init>(CheckedTextView.java:67)
at android.widget.CheckedTextView.<init>(CheckedTextView.java:58)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:467)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$InvokeListBox$MyArrayListAdapter.getView(WebViewClassic.java:12642)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2008)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1247)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1140)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Can you add your XML code

Comment: There is some problem in your XML at line #17

Comment: Fixed stack trace format.